# Google-App-Engine[PHP]: Error trying to establish database connection

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, google-app-engine

I am finding a problem with the cloudsql as database connection is not being established. I have followed the following site step-by-step https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project/

However I seem to be finding problems after deploying the project to the appengine and accessing the wordpress installation page with URL: `https://<PROJECT-ID>.appspot.com/wp-admin/install.php`

The error shown is:

```
**Error establishing a database connection**


/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define( 'DB_NAME', 'wordpress_db' );

/** MySQL database username */
define( 'DB_USER', 'root' );

/** MySQL database password */
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', '' );
```

Can someone please advise a suitable solution to this error, as I cannot get around it and even though I am able to deploy my project. Without a database connection I cannot install Wordpress on cloudsql accordingly.

Comment: can you connect to your running SQL instance on the command line?

Comment: Yes I can through command line I have managed to enter the released IP4 and connect with username and password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem with a work around. Since I was following the instructions from the web page, I researched further on the contributors behind it, leading to the GitHub link:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/wordpress

This was updated as of 2015, and I was able to follow the step-by-step procedure from this URL. I found it necessary to install the GitHub shell commands and clone the project to desktop.

All I needed to do was update the `app.yaml` and `wp-config.php` as required and than create the instance on Cloud SQL, following the 'wordpress' procedure with a new database created as `wordpress_db` and a new `root` user with a blank password.